# check if docker container is running before removing or deleting it via script

Tags: bash, docker, shell, dockerfile

I have a bash script that deploys an application called `enhanced-app`. It is expected to clean up all running containers first before building a new image. My current code does that, but in cases where the container doesn't exist or isn't running, I get an error.

I want to only run the cleanup command if `enhanced-app` is running. Please how can I achieve this?

```
!/bin/bash

echo "Stopping App2..."
docker container stop enhanced-app
docker container rm enhanced-app

CURPATH=$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")

docker build . -t enhanced-app

docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name  enhanced-app enhanced-app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the output of `docker ps` for that:

```
#!/bin/bash

IS_RUNNING=$(docker ps --filter name=enhanced-app --format '{{.ID}}')
if [ -n "${IS_RUNNING}" ]; then
    echo "enhanced-app is running. Stopping App2 and removing container..."
    docker container stop enhanced-app
    docker container rm enhanced-app
else
    IS_STOPPED=$(docker ps -a --filter name=enhanced-app --format '{{.ID}}')
    if [ -n "${IS_STOPPED}" ]; then
        echo "enhanced-app is stopped. Removing container..."
        docker container rm enhanced-app
    else
fi

CURPATH=$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")

docker build . -t enhanced-app

docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name  enhanced-app enhanced-app
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exit status for `docker container inspect`

```
if docker inspect -f 'Container exists and is {{.State.Status}}' enhanced-app; then
  docker container stop enhanced-app
  docker container rm enhanced-app
fi
```

Comment: Did you intentionally swap the order of `rm` and `stop`? If so, could you explain please?

Comment: That was accidental. You had it in the right order